# How to send data from one component to another in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I'm working in nextjs.I have header component and in order to show header in all other pages ,overrided app.js with _app.js .Header has 2 navigation link usersList and users.
Now I want to send data from header component to another page say usersList and users on click of submit in header.How we can achieve that .
I know that we can use context .I'm using class based component don't  know weather we can use context.
Is there any other solution to this problem..
Please help

```
header.js
class HeaderComponent extends Component {
 onSearch(event){
       //some code
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar">

                          <Input id="search-input" className="text-box" placeholder="Enter name or Email.." onKeyDown={($event)=>this.onSearch($event)} prefix={<Icon type="search" onClick={()=>this.onSearch} ></Icon>}></Input>


            </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default HeaderComponent
```

Layout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

class Layout extends Component {
  render () {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
      <div className='layout'>
        <Header />
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

_app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

userList.js

```
class AppUser extends Component {
   render() {
       return (
           <Table
             rowKey={data._id}
             columns={this.columns1}

             onExpand={this.onExpand}
             dataSource={data} 
           />
       )
  }
}
```

EDIT : 
can we achieve it through props

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReactRedux to create a store and have it accessible from all components.

https://redux.js.org/api/store [1]